# Expected value of money won

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

In a certain lottery, a cash prize of $\$1,000,000$ is to be awarded to the lottery winner(s). The number of winners follows a distribution of $X\sim \text{Geo}({4\over 5})$. What is the expected amount of money won by a winner?

Comment: Does $\frac45$ mean a success or a failure probability? Does the distribution start from $0$?

Comment: wWhat does $X~Geo(4/5)$ mean?

Comment: It means if there is one winner, Pr(X=1) = 4/5. If there are two, Pr(X=2)=4/25. And so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

There are $n$ winners with a probability of $p(1-p)^{n-1}$ each of which, winning an amount of $10^6\over n$ dollars, hence the average of money that a winner can take home is$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty p(1-p)^{n-1}\cdot{ 10^6\over n}$$where $p={4\over 5}$.

**Remark**

To calculate the latter sum, pull out a ${1\over 1-p}$ from inside the $\sum$ and differentiate w.r.t. $p$.